# CSS .menu, ol, ul Padding

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and I am working on aspx page, in div section then are calling the below code, what does below CSS do?

```
.menu, ol, ul
{ padding: 0 0 0 0; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model), the padding is the area between the `border` and the content, as apposed to the [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) that is the area around the `border`. `padding: 0 0 0 0;` is a shorthand for setting all [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) values to 0 in the following order: top, right, bottom, left. (It could be abbreviated even further to simply `padding: 0;`, see below)

So, `padding: 5px 10px 15px 20px;` would be equivalent to the following values:

```css
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 20px;
```

You can also only set 1 value to have it applied to all 4 sides (`padding: 5px;`), or two values (`padding: 5px 10px;`), with the first one being applied to top/bottom and the second one to left/right. If you set three values (`padding: 5px 10px 8px;`), those will be applied to top, left/right and bottom.

In your specific case, this rule is applied to all elements with the [class attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) containing `menu`, as well as to all `<ol>` and `<ul>` elements by the [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), which is the part before the curly braces.

Comment: Thanks Constantin for the detailed explanation will go through your pointers

Answer (score 0):

.menu, ol, ul{ padding: 0 0 0 0; }

This means  [ .menu, ol, ul ] has by defualt value. By padding: 0 0 0 0; it will reset to 0 for all direction.